# Can I integrate Dropbox in a Javasccript application (upload, download, delete and update existing files)

Tags: javascript, dropbox

Is there a JavaScript API for Dropbox?

I used Chooser to upload and download files and it is working fine. But I am not able to delete files. I don't know if we can update the existing files in the dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js

(Adding more characters to satisfy StackOverflow.)